# How do I handle real time search of a database in a Django web app?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to build a web app where a user is brought to a webpage with a search bar, and upon every keystroke the results of the search should be displayed below the search bar.

What I have done so far is setup some javascript code to hide and display HTML list elements upon every key stroke, but this isn't exactly searching the database. I suppose I could list the whole database (about 500 objects and growing) in the HTML code and then filter it with Javascript, but I feel like this is inefficient?

A couple of ideas that I have that might work:
1) What I just described above. List the whole database in HTML and filter using javascript.
2) Algolia or elasticsearch search framework? I tried working with both of these and couldn't seem to get them to work.

How should I go about doing this in your opinion? I'm new to web development and i'm unsure what is the best route to take. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your question is quite broad but I would suggest using Elasticsearch. Perhaps this article gets you started. https://itnext.io/elasticsearch-autocomplete-for-django-9dffef1d3afb

Comment: But to implement search as you enter characters, you need Ajax.

Comment: Someone suggested to me that since I'm only dealing with about 1000 objects or less, I would be able to query the online database via API upon every keystroke. Do you think this would be ok?

Comment: The number of objects is not relevant. As I said, you can use Ajax to do that query on every keystroke.

Comment: So would I just build a table in HTML of all the objects in the database and then use Ajax to filter the HTML table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way most (or many) people do this is with an autocomplete (like [jQuery](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)) on the front end and an endpoint to query the DB.

```
  $( "#search_input" ).autocomplete({source: "/search_view"});
```

And `/search_view` would go to a view that returns JSON.
Maybe something like this.

```
def search_view(request):
    term = request.GET.get('term')
    data = []
    if term:
        items = Item.objects.filter(value__icontains=term).values('value', 'id')
        data = json.dumps(items)  

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

There are tons of other things that could be done, this is just a bog simple example.